# Interact with "system-wide" media player

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, media-player, windows-10

I want to develop a music app for Windows 10 and I'm curious about the interface provided by Groove Music next to the volume bar. I've tried Googling to get more information about it but I haven't had any success whatsoever. When I'm playing music in Groove Music and I raise or lower the volume, the name as well as the artist and album artwork of the current song show up with music controls next to the volume indicator this:

[image: screen shot]

I was wondering how I could create this dialog in my own app and what windows API's I'd have to look into.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to access information on a song playing in Groove Music programmatically. I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to add my input to this even though there is a great answer already by [@Stamos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900552/184746), because I've found that it is actually possible to use `SystemMediaTransportControls` from a native windows app (not only a universal app).

First thing, it does still require a reference to the universal `winmd` files, so it will only work on Win10. They will be located in the 10 sdk, and you can add them via the regular `Add Reference -> Browse` but you may need to change the filter on the bottom right of the dialog to "All Files" for them to show up. They are found here on my PC:

- `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract`: 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
- `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract`: 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd

After you have the necessary references, you'll run into another problem - you can't access the transport controls via the usual `SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();` (it will throw an exception) because you don't actually have a universal view. This is alleviated by using the following:

```
SystemMediaTransportControls systemControls =
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
```

After this, feel free to use any of the samples online or Stamos' answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278677)

Here is a basic setup with Play and Pause. If you like to enable more controls you can do using the available properties for ex.

`systemControls.IsNextEnabled = true;`

and you have to add the `case` in the button switch.

```
case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Next:
                    //handle next song
                    break;
```

xaml

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Height="100" Width="100" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>
```

C#

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();

    // Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.
    systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;

    mediaElement.CurrentStateChanged += MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged;


    systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
    systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
}

private void MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (mediaElement.CurrentState)
    {
        case MediaElementState.Playing:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Paused:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Stopped:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Closed:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}



void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Button)
    {
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
            PlayMedia();
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
            PauseMedia();
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Stop:
            StopMedia();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private async void StopMedia()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        mediaElement.Stop();
    });
}

async void PlayMedia()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        if (mediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            mediaElement.Pause();
        else
            mediaElement.Play();
    });
}

async void PauseMedia()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        mediaElement.Pause();
    });
}
```

Output

[image: Output]

Also if you want all this to work in background you will have to do a Declaration in `Package.appxmanifest` for a Background Tasks, enable audio and add an entry point like `TestUWP.MainPage`

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but i did find a way to use this from a native app as well, so I've also posted an answer detailing this.

Answer (score -1):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Media"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls 
            Style="{StaticResource MediaTCStyle}"/>
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

The style is quite big so i'm attaching a link
[MediaTransportControls styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt414180.aspx)
I got the style from the article(link above) and modified it in my own ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Right, the proper thing to use now is `SystemMediaTransportControls`, this answer led me to it. Still curious if there is any way to access this as a native windows app instead of a universal app.

Comment: @caesay `SystemMediaTransportControls` is only evailable to 'Metro' apps also @DanielFilipov TransportControls are for the MediaElements default control in the Element itself not the SystemMediaTransportControls.

Comment: @Stamos I agree and your answer is more clear but still i don't see why would you put a down vote after other already commented it is useful.

Comment: @DanielFilipov As I said in my comment TransportControls are for the MediaElement default controls and   its not the same as SystemMediaTransportControl. I down voted because its not the answer and has nothink yo do with your question.