# Access System Media Controls

Tags: node.js, .net, windows

I'm looking for a solution to access the system media controls/status etc.

I'm language agnostic, so long as I can run it from a node application (native module, executable to stdout, etc.)

My ultimate goal is to access media status cross-platform, but I'll settle for Windows to start as Linux and macOS probably have a different method of accessing this data.

This is the sort of data/functions I'm looking for if it's possible:

- Title
- Playing / Paused
- Control (Can currently do this with the keyboard media controls using robot.js, but a native method would be nice to have)

Comment: Your question is practically identical to this existing one, so it may provide some useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464317/interact-with-system-wide-media-player Although I think this is such a broad question that StackOverflow might just be the wrong place to ask.

Comment: The answer here is to create controls, what I'm looking for is to pull this data from the system. I'll remove the screenshot to remove confusion

Comment: Is there a native windows function/method for it? "ffi" could be a solution if so.