# Adding new item to volume banner popup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, volume

[image: Volume popup banner]

Hi,

I want to make a music player(WinForms/C#) which also adds one entry to the volume control popup, being able to play/pause by pressing media buttons on mouse/keyboard, while having your app minimized, like Chrome/Spotify/Groove Music etc. do (photo above).

All that I could find was "How to get rid of volume control"-sorta results. Is there some embedded library that can come handy ? Or any other working solution would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Per @RaymondChen, I think [system media transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols?view=winrt-22000) are what you are looking for. And [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls) has some C# for manually setting it up if the automatic setup won't work for you.

Comment: Yes! That's the one! Unfortunately, I have no experience using UWP apps and I have barely an idea on how to get started. I hoped for an easier solution trough winforms

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31464317/2557128) seem to be what you want? I added [this project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) to get the necessary references (to LINQPad).